# Recaptcha for stripe checkout

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, recaptcha

I'm facing card testing attack lately on a website that uses stripe checkout.
After two days of being under attack, I finally deactivate the concerned page which leaves my website without any way to pay for services.

Now I would like to add a recaptcha to protect the stripe button, but just can't seem to understand how to do it.

I have a page with three services, under each one is a stripe checkout button. What I would like to do is to prevent bots to access the Stripe checkout page, which is external and hosted on stripe servers.

I did recaptcha integrations before in php and with a regular form. Here I'm working with nodejs and there's no real form to query. Is it possible to prevent bots from accessing those buttons ?

I saw some tutorials online but everytime the form is hosted on local server.

If you have a clue, it would be a great help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the official Google docs for reCAPTCHA v3? They provide code snippets and go into detail about how to do this.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3

It's easiest to implement it in the payment flow *before* your customers ever get to the page with the Checkout button (e.g. on the shopping cart page), but you can also bind it to the form action that triggers the creation of the Checkout Session.